# vueJS data property reactivity issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

i have 2 data properties object, when i click button '**Envoyer**',i push to the second property, i don't want the second proprety data change automatically.

ex : [image]

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It's not clear from the description what you're trying to do, and you haven't shown any code for us to debug or improve.